# Turn off JavaDoc Tooltip in Eclipse's content assist

Tags: eclipse, tooltip, javadoc, content-assist

does anyone know a way to do the above? I'm trying to take some Content Assist screenshots and I don't want the JavaDoc tooltip beside the Content Assist.

At the moment my work-around is to use resizing of the JavaDoc tooltip after it appears so that I can reposition it to somewhere out of the way.

However I have to do this each time I activate content assist, and I would just like the option to turn the tooltip off completely.

Thanks